# Quill editor not firing (change) event in when i change toolbar

Tags: angular

I have below code for capturing quill editor event, but when i change something from toolbar that event is not capturing, how i get this event?

```html
<quill-editor [formControl]="termsAndConditionsForm" 
              [styles]="{ flex: '1 1 auto' }" 
              (keyup)="contentChanged(termsAndConditions, $event)" 
              (onSelectionChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"
              class="quill card" fxFlex="auto" fxLayout="column">
</quill-editor>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onContentChanged` event.

`onSelectionChanged` is only emitted for text selection changes.

`onContentChanged` emits when content changes. It returns `undefined` if nothing has changed but you even made a toolbar action.

So with your code it'll look like:

```html
<quill-editor [formControl]="termsAndConditionsForm" 
              [styles]="{ flex: '1 1 auto' }" 
              (keyup)="contentChanged(termsAndConditions, $event)" 
              (onSelectionChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"
              (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)
              class="quill card" fxFlex="auto" fxLayout="column">
</quill-editor>
```

```js
onContentChanged = (event) =>{
  if (event.html) {
    // Do whatever you want here
    console.log('The content has changed', event.html);
  }
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-rdc91c)
(check the messages in the console)